# How to know if a 4K monitor with 2x HDMI supports 60Hz on both?

Tags: monitors

I am looking at buying a cheap-ish 4K monitor to use with my computer as well as an Xbox Series X and a PS5.

As such I need at least 3 inputs. The computer can do Displayport, the two consoles only HDMI.

As such, I need at least the following:

- 1x Displayport capable of 4K @ 60Hz
- 2x HDMI capable of 4K @ 60Hz

Last time I purchased a monitor I ended up with a Philips after two rounds of returning the unit to the store because they kept promising that both the HDMI ports supported 4K @ 60Hz, when in truth only one of them did.

This piece of information is not readily available either, so how can I know what the ports support? Most of the time they just say "supports 4K @ 60Hz, and got 2 HDMI ports", and that included the two monitors I had to return as well as the third I finally got that supported it.

Specifically, I'm looking at this monitor here:

> [Samsung LU28R550UQUXEN 28"](https://www.samsung.com/ie/monitors/high-resolution/uhd-monitor-28-inch-lu28r550uquxen/)

This lists two HDMI ports and the specs also says HDMI version 2, but that's exactly what the two Philips models I had to return did as well, they just silently hid that the 60Hz support was only available on one port.

My fallback plan is to just make it the stores problem, again, by explicitly stating I need a monitor with two HDMI ports with support for 4K @ 60Hz, and then just keep returning it until they give me one that works, but this makes it hard to sort of figure out what kind of budget I need.

Any advice would be most welcome.

Comment: I presume you mean 60Hz. fps is not in the slightest related to the monitor's refresh frequency.

Comment: Yes, correct, though it would be very hard for a 30Hz monitor to support 60fps, so I don't think it is "not in the slightest related", but you're right, I used the wrong terminology.

Comment: People often have difficulty grasping this, but they are actually unrelated. Of course you won't be able to see 60fps on a 30Hz screen, but that doesn't mean the GPU isn't transmitting it, it just can't be displayed. fps is often an entirely unrelated number to screen refresh - play a game & watch the fps counter go up & down, yet the screen will just plod along at the same refresh rate.

Comment: @Tetsujin I know, you're right. And when you're right, you're right :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot tell easily from the samsung monitor, but you can also get the [LG 27UL550-W (link to Tweakers)](https://tweakers.net/pricewatch/1338760/lg-27ul550-w-zwart/specificaties/), which, according to [DisplaySpecs](https://www.displayspecifications.com/en/model/09ac17f7) has double HDMI 2.0 and DP 1.4. The features and price are similar (both IPS, both 4K 60Hz, both FreeSync, the LG is about €90 cheaper where I live)  so if your shop has both, first try the LG, if it doesn't work, continue blaming the shop if they didn't tell you that it maybe does not have double HDMI 2.0.

Comment: It looks like that particular model is not available around me, but [this one: LG 27" 27UP650-W](https://www.displayspecifications.com/en/model/b126265a) is, which according to DisplaySpecs also has 2x HDMI 2.0.

Comment: Your answer answered my question though, by mentioning DisplaySpecs. That site was new to me, so by using it I should be able to find the information I need for monitors I can look at. Thanks!